# How to change from button to href format?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Can I make this link in a href format (`ahref ='...'`)?

```
<form action='add_to_card.php' method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id?>' />
<input type='submit' value='Add' />
</form>
```

I've tried

```
echo "<a href='add_to_card.php?id=$id'>Add</a>";
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="add_to_cart.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" > Add </a>
```

And make sure that your form uses GET to parse variables.

As POST...

```
<form name="form1" action='add_to_card.php' method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id?>' />
<a href="##" onClick="fn_submit();" >Submit</a>
</form>

<script>
function fn_submit()
{
document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

This way you can put your anchors anywhere and submit form1

Comment: @user1711126 we can't send data using post in href.

Answer (score 1):

easy as cake:

```
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class='add2cart' value='Add to Cart' />
<script>
$('.add2cart').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/add_to_cart.php?id=" + e.currentTarget.id}).done(function( html ) {
   $("body").html(html);
});     
});
</script>

This is through jQuery though. The advantage is that not the whole page gets reloaded.
```

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant!

Comment: why not? the only thing he's sending is the id. So why use a whole form for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to submit form by clicking a link:

```
<form name="myform" action='add_to_card.php' method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id?>' />
<a href="#" onclick="submitform()">Add</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```